# Windows keyboard layout not working in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 but I have a problem with the keyboard layout.

I have a Windows standard keyboard which does not have any multimedia buttons on it. After installing Ubuntu my <kbd>Delete</kbd> has become <kbd>Power Off</kbd>, <kbd>Insert</kbd> is now <kbd>Sleep</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> is <kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd> is <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd> is <kbd>4</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd> is <kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>... Even some of the function keys have become different combinations.

Result for `settings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` is `[('xkb', 'us')]`

Result for `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current` is `uint32 0`

[image: My keyboard look]

How can I fix this?

**Best Answer:**
Below answer solved this problem, but need to repeat again after every update...

I think there is bug or huge issues in new Ubuntu 16.04 updates.

Comment: Can you please tell us: the Ubuntu keyboard layout (i.e. UK, US, India, etc), and the Windows keyboard layout?

Comment: Also, is there no option in Settings → Keyboard for this?

Comment: I am using English (US) layout in ubuntu

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of the commands `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` and `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson see my edit

Comment: I see; it confirms that you have the basic _English (US)_ keyboard layout, and it sounds as if it doesn't match your physical keyboard. You may want to open _System Settings -> Text Entry_ and add and try one or more other English layouts. I can't really say which one would fit. Possibly, if you can take a picture of your physical keyboard and include it in your question, it might help.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson i already try too many layout to solve this problem some of them (English (UK), English(UK, extended WinKeys), English (India with rupee sign), English (International)).... none left to try i think..

Comment: The answer posted by Panagiotis Tabakis looks interesting, but I'm in doubt about the keyboard model. You can find out your currently set model by running the command `setxkbmap -query`. If it's already _pc105_, I have a feeling that you need something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of formatting I will add my comment as an answer.

I have a similar keyboard and I use English (US) and Greek languages. I can show you how to reconfigure your keyboard layout via the command line.

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

This will launch the package configuration for keyboard in the terminal. You can navigate to selections with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and select with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

On keyboard model select: *Generic 105-key (Intl) PC*

[image: Keyboard Model]

On Country of origin of the keyboard select *English (US)*

[image: Country of origin of the keyboard]

On keyboard layout select *English (US)*

[image: Keyboard layout]

On Key to function as AltGr select *The default for the keyboard layout*

[image: Key to function as AltGr]

On Compose key select *No compose key*

[image: Compose key]

On Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to terminate the X server select *No* (or yes if you prefer)

[image: terminate the X server]

Hopefuly this will configure your keyboard properly.

Comment: problem is solved now...